# bootstrap navbar collapse/toggle menu appearing straight away

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, responsive-design

I have made a bootstrap responsive navigation menu, where it collapses into a box when the page gets small. Pretty much the standard one with bootstrap. However, when the page gets small the menu appears out automatically instead of me having to click the toggle box. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
 <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only"> Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button> 
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse" collapse">

<div id="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center"> 
    <li><a href="#">Budget Tracker</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Interactive Globe</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Travel Quiz</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
</div>
```

This is the code for my bootstrap collapsable menu.

Also does anyone know how to make the toggle box appear in the center of the screen, rather than on the right?

Comment: ah yes it was the " between the class!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `"` that's breaking up the classes in `navbar-collapse`

Answer (score 1):

It was the " between the "navbar-collapse" collapse" classes

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the wrong element with your data-target. Give this a shot.

```
 button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-          target="#navigation">
```

Also,  [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp) has a great tutorial on this.